# Does git-fetch copy down the entire repository?

Tags: git, version-control

Does the `git fetch` command copy down the entire remote repository to my machine, or just the upstream of my current branch?

Comment: git fetch fetches branches commits from origin, whithout doing merges. If you want to make a copy of a repo, use git clone. See answers on this question for further insights http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/whats-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch

Comment: Entire repository may not be the best description.  Fetch will get all of the commits in all of the branches since your last fetch/clone.  Any history you already have won't be copied down again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by default it fetches all 'named heads or tags' for the `<repository>` specified.

Comment: So are branches 'named heads'?

Comment: Yes, branches are 'named heads'.

Comment: I think my confusion comes from using `git push` and `git pull`. Don't they only operate on the current branch?

Comment: Yes, they only operate on the current branch.  `git pull` is doing a fetch followed by a merge - which changes the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the options that you use.  It can do both.  It updates the repository with the data but doesn't merge the changes with your local.  That would be with `git pull` or `git merge`.  (`git pull` per the documentation is a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`)

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html